# Blocked by CORS policy from an express server deployed on Firebase Functions even though cors defined

Tags: firebase, express, cors

I deployed my express app on Firebase Functions with `cors` setting. However, on the browser, the below error printed on the console.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://....cloudfunctions.net/users/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

On my code,

```
...
import * as cors from 'cors'

const app = express()

app.use(cors({ origin: true })) // Set CORS properly
app.use(helmet())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use('/', router)

app.use(errorHandler)

export const users = functions
  .region('asia-northeast3')
  .https.onRequest(app)
```

I cannot find what is the problem. Even the official document recommends `app.use(cors({ origin: true}))`. How can I solve this problem?

====EDIT====

My request looks like:

```
GET /baggle-318109/us-central1/auth/kakao HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ko-KR,ko;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
If-None-Match: W/"d-vfAVvdILIkmIo67j2sc7s17+9M0"
```

Comment: How is the request looking alike?

Comment: @LajosArpad Sorry for late response. I used my request using `fetch` function in React app. It looks like `fetch("https://...cloudfunctions.net/users).then(response...)`.

Comment: I meant the actual request that you can see in the browser's Dev Tools -> Network tab

Comment: @LajosArpad I attached the request from Dev Tools > Network tab :) I'm not sure this is what you want to look at.

Comment: Byron, this is half of the info that I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send a request from localhost:3000 to localhost:5001. So, basically you use different URLs (differing by port number) and that throws a CORS error, that is saying to you that

- you have a different origin from the target
- the target did not allow you to do so

The solution is simple: make the target allowing you to do this. Before you continue, read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

You will need to have a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in your response at localhost:5001. You could specify a wildcard of

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

to allow any origin to send a request. You may allow a single source, by putting the source as a value instead of `*`. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Changing the response headers and adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a topic by itself and can be done differently for different servers. You will need to know what server you use for your project that's triggered when you request on localhost:5001 and to look up how can you add this header there.